# How do I include the region in language.code?

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I'm building a language switcher for Django. There are tons of examples but none of them seem to solve the issue I'm having. I always get the short version of the language code. Instead of `en-us` I get `en`.

```
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
{% for language in languages %}

  <a href="/{{ language.code }}{{ request.get_full_path|slice:'6:' }}"
     class="{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %}selected{% endif %}"
     lang="{{ language.code }}">
      {{ language.name }}
  </a>
{% endfor %}
```

My LANGUAGES in `settings.py` are specified as:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en-us', _('English')),
    ('fr-ca', _('French (Canada)')),
)
```

I assumed that `{{ language.code }}` would give me either `en-us` or `fr-ca`. Instead I get `en` and `fr`. Just to be sure I checked if `LANGUAGE_CODE` works and it does return `en-us` as expected. It's just `get_language_info_list` that doesn't seem to work for me.

I feel like I'm missing something extremely simple here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be simple. Even though I read the documentation several times, reading it again in the morning after Nazkter's answer was probably what I needed, thanks!

It turns out that:

```
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
```

Is not needed. A simpler version is:

```
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
{% for CODE, NAME in LANGUAGES %}

  <a href="/{{ CODE }}{{ request.get_full_path|slice:'6:' }}"
     class="mx-3 {% if CODE == LANGUAGE_CODE %}selected{% endif %}"
     lang="{{ CODE }}">{{ NAME }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Note that this only works for full language codes, e.g. `en-us` as we use `slice:'6'`.

Answer (score 0):

The data that you are looking for is in the `LANGUAGE_CODE` variable. You are already getting it:

```
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
```

it will return the value in lang-region format, something like: en-us.

this is the documentation in case you are looking for more variables like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/translation/#get-current-language

Comment: Sorry if I haven't explained it properly but that wasn't what I'm after. I'm looping over a list of available languages and I'm trying to get the language code of each of them in their full format, so `en-us` instead of `en`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have it, if it is useful for someone. I controll the submision of the form using JavaScript, add a submit button if you need to:

```
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}

      <form id="lang-form" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ request.get_full_path|slice:'6:' }}" />
        <select id="lang-select" class="form-control-sm ml-2 mr-1" name="language">
          {% for CODE, NAME in LANGUAGES %}
            <option value="{{ CODE }}" {% if CODE|lower == LANGUAGE_CODE|lower %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>
              {{ NAME }}<!--({{ CODE }})-->
            </option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </form>
```